# How to install pgrep/pkill on debian wheezy docker image

Tags: docker, debian

There is no pkill/pgrep in the base debian:wheezy docker image

```
# docker run debian:wheezy pkill 
System error: exec: "pkill": executable file not found in $PATH
```

and I can't figure out which package should I install to have these tools

```
# docker run debian:wheezy cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian wheezy main
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian wheezy-updates main
deb http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates main
# docker run debian:wheezy apt-get install procps
E: Unable to locate package procps
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try installing procps in your Dockerfile, or in your container, then commit it and launch the new image

Comment: Sure I already tried procps: 
`# docker run debian:wheezy apt-get install procps`
`E: Unable to locate package procps`

Comment: Might need to update first: `apt update && apt install procps`

Answer (score 29):

Solved. I forgot about

```
apt-get update
```

before

```
apt-get install procps
```

in the container

Answer (score 0):

You could run bash and see it for yourself:

`$ docker run --rm -it debian:wheezy bash`

From here you can use apt-get or aptitude and search the packages. I couldn't find pkill (is it a Unix command instead of GNU/Linux?) but I'm guessing you can use `grep` and `kill` together to get the same effect.